# Statistics 2x2 Tables Labels

Tags: tables

How can I adjust my code to include the labels I want at the top? I've attached what this outputs and where I'm trying to add labels (where I'm struggling).

```
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc|c}
& $V$ & $V^\prime$ & $\Sigma$ \\
 \hline
1/2 & 2925 & 3575 & 6500 \\
3+ & 805 & 2695 & 3500 \\
 \hline
$\Sigma$ & 3730 & 6270 & 10000 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

[image: What my source outputs]

[image: What I want to try output]

Comment: Please complete the code: documentclass, begin and end of document, packages used, if relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, to give you some ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{TV Programmes Watched}\\ % one way to do it; you probably want float
        
        \begin{tabular}{cr|cc|c}    % add a column
            \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}|}% merge first two, p allows linebreak
                {Questions answerd correctly} 
                & $V$ & $V^\prime$ & $\Sigma$ \\
            \hline
            & 1/2 & 2925 & 3575 & 6500 \\
            & 3+ & 805 & 2695 & 3500 \\
            \hline
            & $\Sigma$ & 3730 & 6270 & 10000 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}   
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

You can expand on this and include a centered empty and merged line on top, to put the TV-remark. There are more options, depending on what you really want as a result (table caption on top? other things?).

**P.S.**: Regarding your comment, yes, Latex is complex and overwhelming. I suggest spending some time on introductory material, or the User manuals almost all packages do provide. It may also be a good idea to follow at least the tags of your question, or search here, to get a better feel of possibilities, limitations, alternatives of the various packages, e.g. `tabular` :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have too good of an understanding of how multicolumn worked so the comments you included were actually very helpful for learning how to use these.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more complex solution (for exercise how to use `tabularray` package :-) ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{Y}[1][]{>{$\displaystyle}Q[co=1,#1]<{$}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{TV Programmes Watched}
\begin{tblr}{width=0.8\linewidth,
             hline{2,Y}, vline{2,Y},
             colspec={Y[1.5,r] *{3}{Y[0.4,c]} }
             }  
\mbox{Questions answered correctly}
        & V     & V\prime   & \sum  \\
1/2     & 2925  & 3575      &  6500 \\
3+      &  805  & 2695      &  3500 \\
\sum    & 3730  & 6270      & 10000 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
An example, when you like to have the first column header in two lines and consequently narrower table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{Y}[1][]{>{$\displaystyle}Q[co=1,#1]<{$}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{TV Programmes Watched}
\begin{tblr}{width=0.6\linewidth,  % <---
             hline{2,Y}, vline{2,Y},
             colspec={Y[1.3,r] *{3}{Y[0.4,c]} }
             }
\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedleft   
                    Questions answered correctly} % <---
        & V     & V\prime   & \sum  \\
1/2     & 2925  & 3575      &  6500 \\
3+      &  805  & 2695      &  3500 \\
\sum    & 3730  & 6270      & 10000 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!